# R dplyr methods inside own function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Consider this dplyr treatment to a data frame:

```
existing.df <- filter(existing.df, justanEx > 0) %>%
                arrange(desc(justanEx)) %>%
                mutate(mean = mean(justanEx), 
                median = median(justanEx),
                rank = seq_len(length(anotherVar)))
```

I have to do this a lot on an job I'm doing, so I tried making a function for it:

```
df.overZ <- function(data, var){
        df <- data %>% filter(var > 0) %>%
                arrange_(desc((var))) %>%
                mutate(mean = mean(var),
                median = median(var),
                rank = seq_len(length(anotherVar)))
        df
}
```

and them

```
existing.df <- df.overZ(existing.df, "realVar")
```

but this gives me this error:

```
Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
  incorrect size (1), expecting : 50000
```

If I try:

```
existing.df <- df.overZ(existing.df, realVar)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : obj 'realVar' not found
```

I have already tried filter_, arrange_ and mutate_,

but nothing sens to work.

Can this work?

The following function works, though:

```
make.df <- function(var, n){
        df <- orign.df %>% filter(!is.na(var)) %>%
                select(1:2,n,3:6)
        df
}

existing.df <- make.df("oneVar",7)
```

Comment: What are the error messages? Also, please provide some example data (contents of `data.df`).

Comment: Please show a small example data using `dput` and expected output based on that

Comment: [This could help](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)

Comment: added error messages. Notice that this has to work on a existing data.frame, any data.frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released `0.6.0`), we can make use of the `quosures`

```
library(dplyr)
df.overZ <- function(data, Var){
          Var <- enquo(Var)
         data %>%
               filter(UQ(Var) > 0) %>%
               arrange(desc(UQ(Var))) %>%
               mutate(Mean = mean(UQ(Var)),
                      Median = median(UQ(Var)),
                      rank = row_number())

 }

df.overZ(iris, Sepal.Length)
```

We can extend this function to have a `group_by` option as well

```
df.overZ2 <- function(data, Var, grpVar){
          Var <- enquo(Var)
          grpVar <- enquo(grpVar)
          newVar <- paste(quo_name(Var), c("Mean", "Median", "Rank"), sep="_")
         data %>%
               filter(UQ(Var) > 0) %>%
               arrange(desc(UQ(Var))) %>%
               group_by(UQ(grpVar)) %>%
               summarise(UQ(newVar[1]) := mean(UQ(Var)),
                      UQ(newVar[2]) := median(UQ(Var)),
                      UQ(newVar[3]) := n())

}

df.overZ2(iris, Sepal.Length, Species)
# A tibble: 3 × 4
#    Species Sepal.Length_Mean Sepal.Length_Median Sepal.Length_Rank
#      <fctr>             <dbl>               <dbl>             <int>
#1     setosa             5.006                 5.0                50
#2 versicolor             5.936                 5.9                50
#3  virginica             6.588                 6.5                50
```

Here, the `enquo` does a similar job as `substitute` from `base R` by taking the input arguments and converting it to `quosure`, then within the functions (`filter/arrange/mutate/summarise/group_by`) we unquote (`!!` or `UQ`) to evaluate it.  We can also name the columns by passing the `quosure` on the lhs of the assignment (`:=`)